# I want to know how to change an image in PyGame with a single mouse click

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import cv2

from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

pygame.init()

img = cv2.imread('DATTGOH 1.png', 1)
img_half = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
cv2.imshow('Thing 1', img_half)

events = pygame.event.get()
for event in events:
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        img = cv2.imread('DATTGOH 2.png', 1)
        img_half = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
        cv2.imshow('Thing 1', img_half)
        pygame.display.update()
        
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

That is my code so far. I've tried looking at other problems and solutions here, but I'm unsure. This is my first time using PyGame, relatively.

[This is the first image labeled "DATTGOH 1".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJqbA.png)

[This is the second image labeled "DATTGOH 2".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3ZFK.png)

I want to know how to change an image in PyGame with a single mouse click.

What I want is for when the screen I clicked, the screen changes from the first image to the second.

Answer (score -1):

```
pygame.init()
width=350;
height=400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (width, height ) )
pygame.display.set_caption('clicked on image')
redSquare = pygame.image.load("images/red-square.png").convert()

x = 20; # x coordnate of image
y = 30; # y coordinate of image
screen.blit(redSquare ,  ( x,y)) # paint to screen
pygame.display.flip() # paint screen one time

running = True
while (running):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Set the x, y postions of the mouse click
            x, y = event.pos
            if redSquare.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
                BlueSquare = pygame.image.load("images/Blue-square.png").convert()
                screen.blit(BlueSquare ,  ( x,y))  
#loop over, quite pygame
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: An explanation of the code provided, would help the future visitors to understand how your solution works.